# javascript: looping through nested object/array and adding property

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I am not very strong with Javascript. I have a nested array which is a JSON representation of the backend data. It shows a list of proofs and the images used in each proof. Its looks like below:

```
var project = [{
    "proof":"Proof_1",
    "images":[
        {
            "image_id":"12469",
            "name":"1911791794.jpg",
        },
        {
            "image_id":"12470",
            "name":"1911802897.jpg"
        },
        {
            "image_id":"12471",
            "name":"1911761073.jpg"
        }
},
{
    "proof":"Proof_2",
    "images":[
        {
            "image_id":"12469",
            "name":"1911791794.jpg",
        },
        {
            "image_id":"12470",
            "name":"1911802897.jpg"
        }
}];
```

I want to add the image_count to each proof section,so that modified data structure looks like this:

```
var project = [{
    "proof":"Proof_1",
    "image_count": 3, //<----this is new property I want to add
    "images":[
        {
            "image_id":"12469",
            ...
```

I checked some answers but because of my lack of understanding javascript iteration properly I am unable to get this done.

When I do:
for (var proof in project)
{
   console.log(proof);
}

I just get `0,1,2`...etc printed. I am not getting this, so I help someone in SO will help me understand how to add this property I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you found a solution please mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/map) method:

```
project = project.map(function (item) {
    item.image_count = item.images.length;
    return item;
});
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/mysryjkr/)

Also, as @Sebastian Lasse pointed out - you should name your array using plural form to avoid confusion (`projects` instead of `project`).

Comment: right. And you should name your arrays in plural - "projects". This is a convention to avoid confusion.

Comment: As I expected. No reason. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` or simple loop

```js
var projects = [{
  "proof": "Proof_1",
  "images": [{
    "image_id": "12469",
    "name": "1911791794.jpg",
  }, {
    "image_id": "12470",
    "name": "1911802897.jpg"
  }, {
    "image_id": "12471",
    "name": "1911761073.jpg"
  }]
}, {
  "proof": "Proof_2",
  "images": [{
    "image_id": "12469",
    "name": "1911791794.jpg",
  }, {
    "image_id": "12470",
    "name": "1911802897.jpg"
  }]
}];

projects = projects.map(function (element) {
  element.image_count = element.images.length;
  return element;
});

console.log(projects);

var len = projects.length, i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    projects[i].image_count = projects[i].images.length;
}

console.log(projects);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could - after correcting the missing `]` error in your JSON - do this :

```js
project.forEach(function(proof) {
    proof.image_count = proof.images.length;
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dLd8wvpb/**

Comment: Actually, he wanted `image_count` instead of `imageCount`.

Comment: @DanielKmak, thank you for that, guess I'm too opiniated to camelCase :(

Comment: Yes, I also wanted to do that at first. `camelCase` is simply too good. :D